# candidate template ignored: could not match 'const type-parameter-0-0 *' against 'char'

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Хотел написать свою библиотеку, начал с шаблонной функции вывода массива. Компилятор ругается: **candidate template ignored: could not match 'const type-parameter-0-0 *' against 'char'**
Где ошибка?

И еще вопрос, если мне надо что бы библиотека лежала в одной директории и main.cpp  в другой, то я подключаю SMKLibrary.h в main.cpp с адресом директории библиотеки. Компилирую main.cpp так: g++ *.cpp && a.out но получаю ошибку. Работает когда все файлы в одной директории, когда в разных нет. Что писать в терминале что бы компилировать сразу с двух разных директорий?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SMKLibrary.h"

int main() {
    char a[5] = {"ASFD"};

    array_print(a,5);

    return 0;
}
```

SMKLibrary.h

```
#ifndef SMKLIBRARY_H
#define SMKLIBRARY_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void array_print(const T * array[], int size);

#endif
```

SMKLibrary.cpp

```
#include "SMKLibrary.h"

template <typename T>
void array_print(const T * array[], int size) {
    int last = size - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << array[last] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Пока что шаблоны компилятор должен видеть полностью, c телом, а не только прототипы. Так что перенесите определение шаблонной функции в .h-файл.
2. В командной строке указывайте не маску `*.cpp`, а все файлы, которые вам нужно компилировать.
3. Замените

`void array_print(const T* array[], int size)`

на

`void array_print(const T array[], int size)`

или на

`void array_print(const T * array, int size)`

Comment: перенес тело функции в хэдер. @Harry Тот же самый error вылазит:  note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const type-parameter-0-0 *' against 'char'

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko Вот ваш код после выполнения 1 и 3 пунктов моего ответа (я просто перенес шаблон прямо в основной файл) - http://ideone.com/0t0OTf - у вас такой же? Компилируется? или дает ошибку?

Comment: Все, я понял о чем вы. Спасибо